# WQL query returns multiple instances in collection

Tags: object, collections, vbscript, sccm, wql

I'm running a WQL query in VBScript to pull data from our SCCM database.  I can do other queries that all work as expected.  They usually return an object collection that I can loop through and access using the standard method:

```
For Each objGroup in colGroups
    wscript.echo objgroup.name
Next
```

when using the the `objgroup.GetObjectText_` method to display the data within one of the collection objects in a working query, I typically see something like:

```
instance of SMS_R_UserGroup
{
    Name = "whatevername";
    UsergroupName = "whatever";
    WindowsNTDomain = "whatever";
};
```

There is essentially a single instance (please correct me if my terminology is wrong) within each object with properties that I can easily access.

With the problematic query, I'm seeing multiple instances within each object:

```
instance of __GENERIC
{
    SMS_G_System_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGURATION = 
instance of SMS_G_System_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGURATION
{
    DefaultIPGateway = "xxxx";
    DHCPEnabled = 1;
    DHCPServer = "xxxx";
    DNSDomain = "xxxx";
    DNSHostName = "xxxx";
    GroupID = 4;
    Index = 9;
    IPAddress = "xxxxxx";
    IPEnabled = 1;
    IPSubnet = "xxxx";
    MACAddress = "xxxx";
    ResourceID = 74762;
    RevisionID = 11;
    ServiceName = "xxxxxx";
    TimeStamp = "xxxxx";
};
    SMS_R_System = 
instance of SMS_R_System
{
    Active = 1;
    ADSiteName = "xxxxxx";
    AgentName = {"xxxxxx"};
    AgentSite = {"xxxxx"};
    AgentTime = {"xxxxxx"};
    AlwaysInternet = 0;
    Client = 1;
    ClientType = 1;
    ClientVersion = "xxxx";
};
```

How do I access the properties in an object with multiple instances?  Why is it returning multiple instances?

By the way, here is the query I'm running:

```
SELECT *
FROM SMS_R_System
JOIN SMS_G_System_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGURATION ON
  SMS_G_System_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGURATION.ResourceID = SMS_R_System.ResourceID
WHERE SMS_R_System.Name = 'xxxxxx' AND
  SMS_G_System_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGURATION.IPAddress IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You're JOIN'ing SMS_R_System and SMS_G_System_NETWORK_ADAPTER_CONFIGURATION. This will yield one record for each NIC config. If the device has multiple NICs (including virtual ones) with non-null IP addresses (which could include private networks), you will get one JOIN'ed record for each. You should be able to see differences in NIC data for each "duplicate" record.